# Como fazer para canvas toDataURL funcionar em imagens em outro servidor?

Tags: facebook, canvas

Tenho um app do facebook onde pego a imagem do perfil do usuário. Como fazer para colar esta imagem sobre outra fazendo uma montagem para ser depois compartilhada no proprio fb. O método toDataURL do canvas não funciona pq a imagem está em outro servidor. Preciso algum plugin ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Amigo, pelo que vi aqui, o método toDataUrl do canvas, não tem nenhuma restrição de domínio. Quando você tenta usá-lo, qual erro é disparado no console?

Comment: Não dispara nenhum erro, apenas a imagem não aparece

Comment: pelo que já li, esta restrição ocorre para que não haja cópia ou falsificação de imagens com direitos autorais ou algo do tipo

Comment: Você tem razão. Pelo que vi aqui, a solução seria você utilizar um servidor, em backend você não teria esse tipo de restrição

Comment: LF Ziron como assim? Vc tem algum link onde eu possa aprender a fazer isto?

Comment: Resolvi o problema. Basta fazer:    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

Comment: Crie uma resposta para a sua pergunta com essa informação, assim quando outro usuário possuir a mesma dúvida, achará uma solução com mais facilidade

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema. Basta fazer:

```
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```